# Adding GroundOverlay from KML to MKMapView with rotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, kml

I have an iOS app where I want to read a KML-file containing GroundOverlays. A GroundOverlay contains an image-href, north, south, east, west coordinates, as well as a a rotation.

I have followed this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial) for displaying the images on the map. I can successfully parse the KML and display non-rotated images correctly. The problem is, I have no idea of how to display rotated images.

To rotate myself I need to know two things: firstly, how do I rotate the image in my drawing code. This question is just about rotating in iOS. Secondly, I need to know how the KML-coordinates are affected by a rotation. Are the north, south, east and west coordinates the coordinates of the rotated or the non-rotated image?

I have searched extensively for examples on how to do this, but found nothing useful. A link to some tutorial/code that does this would be great!

The relevant parts of the KML looks like this:

```
<GroundOverlay>
  <Icon>
    <href>http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/etna.jpg</href>
  </Icon>
  <LatLonBox>
    <north>37.91904192681665</north>
    <south>37.46543388598137</south>
    <east>15.35832653742206</east>
    <west>14.60128369746704</west>
    <rotation>-0.1556640799496235</rotation>
  </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
```

My drawing code (where I guess the rotation should take place):

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

    CGImageRef imageReference = self.overlayImage.CGImage;

    // TODO: rotate image by self.rotation degrees around center.
    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it. Firstly, the KML-coordinates are the coordinates of the un-rotated image, so there is nothing really that needs to be done to make them work with a rotation. Here is the completed drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

    CGImageRef imageReference = self.overlayImage.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
    // Translate to center of image. This is done to rotate around the center, 
    // rather than the edge of the picture
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, theRect.size.width / 2, theRect.size.height / 2);

    // _rotation is the angle from the kml-file, converted to radians.
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, _rotation);

    // Translate back after the rotation.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -theRect.size.width / 2, -theRect.size.height / 2);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}
```

It was quite a while since I wrote this code and I don't really remember more details than this, but since someone just upvoted the question, I thought I'd at least post the code where I solved it. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I am also trying to solve that same problem especially in swift,So,would you mind sharing with an example in github?I also need to know how did you parse that ground overlay with an image.Thanks.Github is unnecessary.Any storage is welcome.

Comment: I got it now.Thanks to your code which i turned into swift.